# Keeping long-hand color value when using stylus functions

Tags: html, css, stylus

I am trying to write a small mixin to create a filter gradient for internet explorer. 
The function is called filter-gradient and takes 2 color parameters.

When you pass a color value of say #ffffff, stylus automatically shortens this to #fff.
Is there a way to maintain the long-hand version?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to keep it longhanded?

Comment: The filter css attribute needs the longhand version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `unquote()` function for this, so the `unquote('#ffffff')` would always give you `#ffffff`, without the shortening.

Comment: this works fine...

 filter-gradient(unquote('#ffffff'), unquote('#000000'))

but i would prefer to put the unquotes in the function itself...

Comment: yeah, in that case you'll need to convert the shorthand to longhand manually, like [someone did in this issue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/issues/581) on stylus' github. Maybe there are better (and shorter) ways of doing so, but I don't know of any.